# XML/php foreach loop not looping all data

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach

It seems my foreach is looping the correct amount of times. However it's only populating the variables with content from the first loop.

I tried it 2 ways. but firstly this is the url to the XML feed
http://wowfeeds.wipeitau.com/GuildActivity.php?location=EU&rn=shadowsong&gn=antheas&output=XML&callback=? so you can see the structure.

the php codee issss

```
function GetAchievements(){
$achurl = "http://wowfeeds.wipeitau.com/GuildActivity.php?location=EU&rn=shadowsong&gn=antheas&limit=100&output=XML&callback=?"; 
$achxml = new SimpleXMLElement($achurl);
// Achievements
foreach ($achxml->ACTIVITYLIST->ACTIVITYITEM as $ach) {
$name = $ach['NAME'];
echo $name;
//$Achievments = "<p><img src='$achimg' /> <span class='red'>$achname</span> $achtext <span class='red'>$achobj</span></p>";
//echo $Achievments;
}
```

}

This seems to just return a blank.

However if I alter the code @ $name = $ach['NAME'] to = $name =

```
    function GetAchievements(){
    $achurl = "http://wowfeeds.wipeitau.com/GuildActivity.php?location=EU&rn=shadowsong&gn=antheas&limit=100&output=XML&callback=?"; 
    $achxml = new SimpleXMLElement($achurl);
    // Achievements
    foreach ($achxml->ACTIVITYLIST->ACTIVITYITEM as $ach) {
    $name = $achxml->ACTIVITYLIST->ACTIVITYITEM->NAME;
    echo $name;
    //$Achievments = "<p><img src='$achimg' /> <span class='red'>$achname</span> $achtext <span class='red'>$achobj</span></p>";
    //echo $Achievments;
    }
}
```

Then it simply repeats the first entry the same number of times as entries.

EG.
Name.
Name.
Name.
This been driving me mad for 2 hours now. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplexml object is not an array, you might need to consider like this

```
$url    = 'http://wowfeeds.wipeitau.com/GuildActivity.php?'.
          'location=EU&rn=shadowsong&gn=antheas&output=XML&callback=?';
$achxml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($achxml->ACTIVITYLIST->ACTIVITYITEM as $ach)
{
  $name = (string) $ach->NAME;
  echo $name, "\n";
}
```

output :

```
Ichex
Azraelka
Brechnor
Rougwar
Bromious
Ziini
Ryoden
Ashlynne
Snappidagg
Flökræ
Flökræ
Sevenfold
Ashlynne
Bonewing
Goldstroke
Flökræ
Worgin
Bromious
Renevatio
Ziini
Flökræ
Flökræ
Strollomiona
Thorban
Ichex
```

Comment: even if i just try to echo/print out $ach->NAME or $ach['NAME']; it still gives me endless loop of the same 1st result though.

Comment: ah, okay, that seems to be doing the job thanks v much, could you explain to me what exactly i was doing wrong and how what you did solved it? thanks :)

Comment: @Owen Melbourne - simplexml object return by the function is not just an associate array, but a collection of simplexmlelement object. Your first example is very close, except you should not use associate array to look for simplexmlelement object, and the use of `new SimpleXMLElement` is not very accurate, it could be caused by the original xml format problem